# Karate Driver iframe element identification challenges

Tags: karate

I am new to Karate Driver and able to automate most of the UI components however facing challenges on elements inside iframe.

I referred https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/README.md

And,

I successfully highlighted iframe by handling sync issues.

Then I tried to input values to text fields and it fails.

Tried “waitFor” for text field element to handle any sync issues.

Tried “Friendly locators” to nearby elements to hit text field etc.

Please advise any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is here for `switchFrame()` https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#switchFrame

Here is an [excerpt from a script](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/core/test-01.feature) that works for me:

```
# switch to iframe by locator
Given driver webUrlBase + '/page-04'
And switchFrame('#frame01')
When input('#eg01InputId', 'hello world')
And click('#eg01SubmitId')
Then match text('#eg01DivId') == 'hello world'
And switchFrame(null)
```

Try in Chrome only, make sure you are using the recent version 0.9.5.RC4 - and if you are still stuck, do try create a sample for us to replicate by following this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you. I was using version 0.9.4 with exact same code snippets that you had shared. I will upgrade to 0.9.5 and try. Also will keep you updated with sample to replicate issues if new version did not solve the issues.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the issue still occurs with 0.9.5. I shall find a similar example by automating a public site and create Github gradle project to share with you. I just made sure my scenario worked fine with selenium java to make sure my xpath selections are right.